# Make cassandra object json serializable

Tags: python, json, object, cassandra

I've got a method for fetching all my data from cassandra database. The problem I am facing is that it returns a cassandra object, while I want json. I've tried multiple solutions but none seem to work. I've tried `json.dumps()` and `loads` but I get an error message saying `object is not JSON serializable`

Any suggestions?

My code:

```
@api.route('/getAllApps')
class getAllApps(Resource):
    @api.marshal_list_with(model)
    def get(self):
        return ar.getAllApplications(), 200
        #if ar.getAllApplications is None:
            #return 204



def getAllApplications(*args):
        for data in AddApplication.objects():
             print(data, data.address, data.gocd, data.jenkins, data.nodes, data.serverDependencies)
             return data
```

Comment: You need to pass `object_hook` to `json.loads`.

Comment: please don't try to get all data from Cassandra! You'll kill your cluster if you have relatively big data there

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As per default setting, cassandra returns query data in tuple format. What you need to do is to change the cassandra configuration to receive it in the dict format.

```
import json
from cassandra.query import ordered_dict_factory

cluster = Cluster(['127.0.0.1'],auth_provider=auth_provider)
session = cluster.connect("keyspace")
session.row_factory = ordered_dict_factory

#query result
rows = self.session.execute_async("SELECT * FROM " + table)
rows = self.return_result(rows, 'data')
data = rows.result()

# dump in json
json.dumps(data)
```

---

Here is the another way, check this [select-json](https://murukeshm.github.io/cassandra/trunk/cql/json.html#select-json) support:

```
 SELECT JSON a, ttl(b) FROM ...
```

Comment: Thank you! Worked perfectly.